# Kubernetes Communication Issues

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a Kubernetes ingress rule set as;

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: ingress-svc
 annotations:
   alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
   alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: IP
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
   - host: api.example.com
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /api/service1
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: svc-service1
               port:
                 number: 3000
         - path: /api/service/service2
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: svc-service2
               port:
                 number: 3000
         - path: /api/service/service3
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: svc-service3
               port:
                 number: 3000
         - path: /api/service/service4
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: svc-service4
               port:
                 number: 3000
```

When I try to access api.example.com/api/service1 it gets the required data from the service SERVICE1 but when I try to access a path in SERVICE2 which makes a request to SERVICE1, I get a 504 Gateway Time-out error.
I have tried accessing SERVICE1 from SERVICE2 using the clusterIP but to no avail and I even tried to access it from SERVICE2 using Axios and SERVICE1 path api.example.com/api/service1 but to no avail.
My services are structured as;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  svc-service1
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: svc-service1
 replicas: 1
 strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 25%
    maxUnavailable: 25%
  type: RollingUpdate
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app:  svc-service1
   spec:
     containers:
      - name:  svc-service1
        image:  IMAGE_PATH
      # imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
         - name: ENV_VAR_1
           value: ENV_VAR_VALUE_1
        ports:
         - containerPort:  3000
           protocol:  TCP
         # restartPolicy: Always

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: svc-service1
spec:
 selector:
   app: svc-service1
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
  - name: svc-service1
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```